# Rule that applies to mails containing Outlook invitations

Tags: mail.app, attachments

I am using the Mail app for my work Exchange account. I am regularly receiving events corresponding to Outlook meeting invitations. I would like to filter these events and move them to a specific Mailbox, but I am not sure how to do that.

Here are some of the rules I have tried setting up:

- Filter by "Any Attachment Name" = contains = .ics
- Filter by "Attachment Type" = Document
- Filter by "Attachment Type" = Executable

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following option for it. I am using and it is working as expected.

[image]

Comment: In my original post I mentioned that this exact rule didn't work.

Comment: Did you try to reflect exactly what I did? I saw your status, but in my side it is working with ends with .ics so I shared my screenshot.

Comment: As of 2023, this is still broken in Mail.app. For whatever reason, this particular rule appears to just get ignored on incoming mail (which I assume is what OP was experiencing). However, if you select a specific email and then right-click —> Apply Rules, it will work just fine (which is probably why it appeared to work for @Uhdy). But if it doesn't just work automatically in the background like all the other rules then it's essentially rendered useless.